# extrude region (vertex normals) direction problem

Tags: modeling

[image]Following tutor4u video making a mic (part 2) I came upon extrude region vertex normals for the mic stand bracket.

Selecting extrude region vertex normals I attempted to add `.1` and enter, but the extrude only moves down in the z direction. Also when I click on extrude region vertex normals with my mouse and slide the mouse over the working window the extrude begins (downward in the z direction) by my just moving the mouse in any direction on working window.

The video does not show any problem like I'm having, I'm sure I have all settings the same as the tutorial. I'm using Blender 2.79 (same as tutorial) only I'm using a mac computer, tutorial appears to be windows OS. I also made sure that I have no vertex duplicates.

Comment: Can you please [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/142828/edit) in a link to tutorial, and perhaps a picture of your mesh in edit mode.  Quite likely it can be fixed by selecting region (or all)  and flipping normals. Or without changing normals, to go in other direction negate the displacement, (-0.1).

Comment: As one option try to use Alt+S to scale along normals after extruding faces. Note that scaling might work only if there aren't any other faces already etruded

Answer (score 1):

If  your Pivot is set to 'Individual Origins', you can indeed get <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > 'Faces Along Normals' in 2.8, or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > 'Region Along Vertex Normals' in 2.79, to fail as shown.

With the Pivot set to any other value, it works as expected.

This does seem like, at least, inconsistent behavior.. I haven't looked to see whether it's already been mentioned to developers.

Comment: Your solution was correct. When I changed pivot point the 'Region Along Vertex Normals' action was the same as the tutorial. I'm glad to get over that hurdle in learning Blender.

Comment: @duane 'features' like this are rare in stable builds -  the devs are doing a great job. You're unlucky to have run into one.